# US visa type for international student offered CTO position

Tags: usa, visa

**Background:** I am from India. I came to the USA for my MS in computer science and am currently on an **F1-student visa**. I have a significant amount of work experience in one field.

**Situation:** There is a USA-based startup that is in a similar field, and they want to offer me a **CTO position**.

**Questions:**

1. What visa category do I fall into?
2. How do I navigate a green card after this, considering I am from India and we have a long wait time for a green card?

Answer (score 3):

> What VISA category do I fall into?

H1b seems the most appropriate. You can probably start on your MS OPT while you wait for it, have the company check with the immigration attorney. Be careful with flashy titles since it may bite you at the labor certification step.

> How do I navigate a green-card after this, considering I am from India and we have a long wait time for a green-card?

You can skip the green card and return to India when the visa expires. That way you don't have to wait.